# Resolve <a> </a> tag issue for not showing perfect result

Tags: html

using this HTML commands in vscode:-->

```
<a>href="page2.html"/>page2</a>
<a>href="https://www.google.com">Google </a>
```

when i refresh the page it is showing web address insted of showing only link ,where we can click
to enter on specifice link address.

It is showing following result:-->

```
href="page2.html"/>page2
href="https://www.google.com">Google
```

Comment: `<a>href="page2.html"/>page2</a>` => `<a href="page2.html">page2</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `href` inside the `<a>` tag, like this:

```
<a href="page2.html">page2</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google </a>
```

Comment: ya it work Samball